# Detect and display computer browser using perl

Tags: perl

Can anyone please tell me how to detect and display computer browser using perl?

Thanks in advance. Please help.

I want the output to be displayed as

```
Firefox (with version number)
```

Comment: well, this problem has very little to do with Perl and a lot about your OS - which you did not even mention.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Browsers often provide a string in the `Agent` header of the HTTP request, which some web servers provide to CGI scripts via the `HTTP_USER_AGENT` environment var.

[HTTP::BrowserDetect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aBrowserDetect) provides tools for extracting information from that string.

```
use CGI                 qw( );
use HTTP::BrowserDetect qw( );

my $cgi = CGI->new();
print $cgi->header('text/plain');

my $bd = HTTP::BrowserDetect->new($cgi->user_agent());
print $bd->browser_string(), ' ', $bf->public_version(), "\n";
```